# Using to_datetime several columns names

Tags: pandas, string-to-datetime

I am working with several CSV's that first N columns are information and then the next Ms (M is big) columns are information regarding a date.

This is the dataframe picture
[image: This is the dataframe picture]

I need to set just the columns between N+1 to N+M - 1 columns name to date format.

I tried this, in this case N+1 = 5, no matter M, I suppose that I can use -1 to not affect the last column name.

```
ContDiarios.columns[5:-1] = pd.to_datetime(ContDiarios.columns[5:-1])
```

but I get the following error:

> TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing is not feasable. Please try this way

```
def convert(x):
    try:
        return pd.to_datetime(x)
    except:
        return x
x.columns = map(convert,x.columns)
```

Or you can also use [df.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) property to convert it.